# Check is a value is in a Drop Down, using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have populated a Drop Down list, using JQuery, using this:

```
$(".cmbSource").html(result.SourceList);
```

Now, I need to check if a particular VALUE is in this list, and if so, I need to set the drop down to this value. If the value doesn't appear in the drop down, I need to default to the first item in the list.

Is there a way to see if a Dropdown list contains a specific value? (Not the display text).

Something like:

```
if($(".cmbSource").contains(67))
...
```

The drop down was populated using .Net code from the Json call that sends back a string, built like this:

```
sourceList += string.Format("<option value='{0}'>{1}</option>", item.Id, item.FullName);
```

Comment: it depends much on the DropDown HTML structure.

Comment: I added the code that builds the html that gets passed in.

Answer (score 0):

Use an attribute selector to match the `value` attribute.

```
var defaultValue = 67;
var defaultOption = $('.cmbSource option[value=' + defaultValue + ']');
if (defaultOption.length == 0) {
    defaultOption = $('.cmbSource option:first');
}
defaultOption.attr('selected', true);
```